# A little issue with Horizontal Menu Drop Down List CSS/HTML/Javascript

Tags: css

I was editing my whmcs template at https://brain.hostug.com.
As you visit and see there is a horizontal Menu in Header. In the option '**About HostUG**', when you hover, it appears the next level menu below. But there is a space before the `li` items.

Can any one help me to remove that space before the li items?

I have attached a screenshot you can see the area in red circle. I want to remove that space.
You can check the right version of this on hostug.com There it is performing well. But i can't figure out what problem I have made while editing in brain.hostug.com

Thank you in advance and waiting for reply.

Comment: Can you post code of your suspected trouble spot? It will help folks help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around line 255 of style.css, you'll find this:

```
.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Add this to it:

```
padding-left: 0;
```

Which should leave you with this:

```
.siteHeader .navigation li ul.dropdown
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just added padding:0px and now it's okay. Thanks alot of your help and time. :)

Answer (score 1):

That looks much like the default `padding` value on `<ul>`. Target it and remove the padding and the space should disappear.

```
.dropdown { padding: 0 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It works. After adding padding:0px in the inner ul it is now okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul { padding:0px; }
li { padding:0px; }
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Glad I could help, I too know the merciless hassle of WHMCS integrations. Good luck with your future endeavours.